# disable overrided tpl file based on module status in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am new to prestashop and using 1.6 version. I am creating a module which will show cart summary in pop up box after adding product into cart. The process of adding product into cart will be triggered, when customer clicks on "Add to cart" button.

So, i want to change the current functionality of "Add to cart button" and put my functionality on this.

I have searched many things on this, but everyone telling me that, this can be achieved by overriding tpl file. Its ok, but i have question on this that, if i override tpl file and after that user disable my module module then in that case, will overrided tpl file work??. Disable means just disable its functionality not uninstall the module.

So, please any one clear my confusion on this and tell me the right solution of how can i change the current functionality of "Add to cart" button and put my funcationality, when my module is enable??

Waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to do an override, by copying the default template, and just remove/add code from it based on that if the module is enabled or disabled/uninstalled. These are just simple IFs, like:

```
{if Module::isInstalled('socialsharing')}
    <div>SOCIAL</div>
{else}
    <div>NO SICIAL</div>
{/if}
```

If course instead of **isInstalled()** method you can use **isEnabledForShopContext()** & **isEnabled()**

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your solution is appreciable but i just want to know that, if my module is disable then the overrided template should not be work. To stop using overrided template if my module is disable, what will i do for this??

Comment: The overrided template always works and you do not have a mechainsm  to hook to module disabling and there to remove the overrided template. The only way to do what you want is with the solution above.